# Teleport a mob to an armor stand when it gets too far from it

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have an armor stand called 'Slime' and I need to teleport a slime called 'KingSlime' to it when it gets 5 blocks away. I tried this with the command:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Slime] ~ ~ ~ /execute @e[type=Slime,name=KingSlime,rm=5] ~ ~ ~ /tp 62 5 18
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/tp` command requires a target. You can remove the second `/execute` and move the selector into `/tp` instead:

```
/execute @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Slime] ~ ~ ~ /tp @e[type=Slime,name=KingSlime,rm=5] 62 5 18
```